# Centos 7 ssh login failed using LDAP and sssd

Tags: linux, ssh, openldap, pam, sssd

I've setup an LDAP server running on Centos 7.  id, getent passwd, on users works.  But 'ssh' failed.  From /var/log/secure, it seems like authentication succeeded, but pam doesn't like something else.  I'm not sure how to narrow down where the problem is.

/var/log/secure:

```
May 11 16:33:40 localhost sshd[45055]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=ldapserver.abc.com  user=user1
May 11 16:33:40 localhost sshd[45055]: pam_sss(sshd:auth): authentication success; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=ldapserver.abc.com user=user1
May 11 16:33:40 localhost sshd[45055]: pam_sss(sshd:account): Access denied for user user1: 6 (Permission denied)
May 11 16:33:40 localhost sshd[45055]: Failed password for user1 from ldapserver.abc.com port 55185 ssh2
May 11 16:33:40 localhost sshd[45055]: fatal: Access denied for user user1 by PAM account configuration [preauth]
```

/etc/sssd/sssd.conf:

```
[sssd]
services = nss, pam, autofs, ssh
config_file_version = 2
domains = default

[nss]
homedir_substring = /home
filter_users = root,ldap,named,avahi,haldaemon,dbus,radiusd,newsnsdc,nscd

[domain/default]
enumerate = False
ldap_tls_reqcert = never
autofs_provider = ldap
cache_credentials = True
krb5_realm = #
ldap_search_base = dc=abc,dc=com
id_provider = ldap
auth_provider = ldap
chpass_provider = ldap
access_provider = ldap
ldap_tls_cacert = /etc/openldap/certs/cacert.pem
ldap_uri = ldaps://ldapserver.abc.com:636
ldap_id_use_start_tls = False
ldap_default_bind_dn = uid=nssproxy,ou=users,dc=abc,dc=com
ldap_chpass_uri = ldaps://ldapserver.abc.com:636

ldap_default_authtok_type = password
ldap_default_authtok = 12345
debug_level = 4

[pam]
debug_level = 4

[sudo]

[autofs]

[ssh]
debug_level = 9

[pac]

[ifp]
```

/etc/pam.d/password-auth-ac:

```
#%PAM-1.0
# This file is auto-generated.
# User changes will be destroyed the next time authconfig is run.
auth        required      pam_env.so
auth        sufficient    pam_unix.so nullok try_first_pass
auth        requisite     pam_succeed_if.so uid >= 1000 quiet_success
auth        sufficient    pam_sss.so use_first_pass
auth        required      pam_deny.so

account     required      pam_unix.so
account     sufficient    pam_localuser.so
account     sufficient    pam_succeed_if.so uid < 1000 quiet
account     [default=bad success=ok user_unknown=ignore] pam_sss.so
account     required      pam_permit.so

password    requisite     pam_pwquality.so try_first_pass local_users_only retry=3 authtok_type=
password    sufficient    pam_unix.so sha512 shadow nullok try_first_pass use_authtok
password    sufficient    pam_sss.so use_authtok
password    required      pam_deny.so

session     optional      pam_keyinit.so revoke
session     required      pam_limits.so
-session     optional      pam_systemd.so
session     [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so service in crond quiet use_uid
session     required      pam_unix.so
session     optional      pam_sss.so
```

/etc/pam.d/system-auth-ac:

```
#%PAM-1.0
# This file is auto-generated.
# User changes will be destroyed the next time authconfig is run.
auth        required      pam_env.so
auth        sufficient    pam_fprintd.so
auth        sufficient    pam_unix.so nullok try_first_pass
auth        requisite     pam_succeed_if.so uid >= 1000 quiet_success
auth        sufficient    pam_sss.so use_first_pass
auth        required      pam_deny.so

account     required      pam_unix.so
account     sufficient    pam_localuser.so
account     sufficient    pam_succeed_if.so uid < 1000 quiet
account     [default=bad success=ok user_unknown=ignore] pam_sss.so
account     required      pam_permit.so

password    requisite     pam_pwquality.so try_first_pass local_users_only retry=3 authtok_type=
password    sufficient    pam_unix.so sha512 shadow nullok try_first_pass use_authtok
password    sufficient    pam_sss.so use_authtok
password    required      pam_deny.so

session     optional      pam_keyinit.so revoke
session     required      pam_limits.so
-session     optional      pam_systemd.so
session     [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so service in crond quiet use_uid
session     required      pam_unix.so
session     optional      pam_sss.so
```

/etc/nsswitch.conf:

```
passwd:     files sss
shadow:     files sss
group:      files sss
#initgroups: files

#hosts:     db files nisplus nis dns
hosts:      files dns

bootparams: nisplus [NOTFOUND=return] files

ethers:     files
netmasks:   files
networks:   files
protocols:  files
rpc:        files
services:   files sss

netgroup:   files sss

publickey:  nisplus

automount:  files sss
aliases:    files nisplus
```

Comment: `sssd` does not support authentication over an unencrypted channel.

Comment: Not a programming question; try https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/linux or https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/linux next time; voted to close.

Answer (score 0):

> sssd does not support authentication over an unencrypted channel

This line from man page should be posted as answer specifically.

Answer (score 0):

Quiet old question, probably problem was solved, but I'll reply to help others peoples with same trouble.

I found a solution here :
https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-server-73/sssd-configuration-problem-4175477396/

At few words :

> If ldap_access_filter isn't configured and filter is in the ldap_access_order (which is the default when it's not specified) all users are denied access.

So ldap_access_filter should be configured even to allow all users to connect. After doing that, my (similar) problem has gone.

Hope it will help somebody.